# How to stop scrolling of page while panel is open and also make panel smooth in iphone/android using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a panel.js. In this js code is:

```
var NavPanelClass = function(ScreenName) {
    var that = {};
    var _panel = $("[name='" + ScreenName + "Panel_NavHTML']").children("#myNavPanel"); 
    _panel.attr("id", ScreenName + "Panel");
    var page = _panel.parents("[data-role=page]");
    page.append(_panel);


    that.open = function() {
        _panel.panel("open");
    };

    that.close = function() {
        _panel.panel("close");
    };

    return that;
};
```

Code of panel.html is:

`** style="background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75); height:70% ; overflow:auto;position: fixed;" data-role="panel" data-position="left" id="myNavPanel" data-display="overlay" data-theme="a" **`

this code is inside div element

I have also `screen.html`. In this html, on page load i am making object using `Panel = new NavPanelClass('Screen');` and there is also a button where i have using `Panel.open()` on button `click.This CartPanel.open()` method open the slidemenubar panel. but there are two problems occur:

when user open the panel and scroll the page then page is scrolling. I do not want to page `scroll.Page` is `NewCartScreen.html`. In this page there is list of items.
2.When I am using this app in iphone/android then it is not much smooth.Means its response for closing and opening is not so good.Means sometimes its not closing properly.

Any Suggestion would be great help.